# Знак препинания во вставных конструкциях со звукоподражательными словами

Tags: пунктуация, тире, вставная-конструкция, междометие

Всегда ли нужно выделять тире вставные конструкции, являющиеся звукоподражательными словами? Например:

> Приз дадут только победителю — ха-ха — мне.

Comment: Дмитрий, на сайте принято благодарить участников за все полезные вопросы и ответы стрелочкой (треугольником) вверх, а также отмечать один из ответов, наиболее понравившийся и решивший проблему, галочкой, как принятый.

Answer (score 2):

[**Ха-ха́**; ха-ха-ха́](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&ro=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D1%85%D0%B0-%D1%85%D0%B0) (БТС)
**I.** ***межд.*** Обозначает смех, хохот. *Схватился за бока и покатился со смеху... Ха-ха! ха-ха! ха-ха!* (Некрасов); *Вся столица содрогнулась, а девица хи-хи-хи да ха-ха-ха!* (Пушкин).
**II.** ***неизм.; ср.*** Смех. *Ничего не знает, кроме хи-хи-хи да ха-ха-ха* (*разг.*; только и смеётся, веселится).
**III.** ***в функц. сказ.*** Смешно, забавно. *Ему всё ха-ха.*

В вашем предложении междометие "ха-ха" употреблено звукоподражательно — для обозначения громкого (ироничного или самоуверенного) смеха.
Оформлять такое звукоподражание можно разными способами (совсем не обязательно использовать вставную конструкцию).
*Приз дадут только победителю — **ха-ха!** — мне.

Приз дадут только победителю. **Ха-ха**, мне!

Приз дадут только победителю. **Ха-ха!** Мне!*

Посмотрите в [**Нацкорпусе**](https://processing.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?lang=ru&sort=i_grtagging&req=%D1%85%D0%B0-%D1%85%D0%B0&g=i_doc&format=html&spp=50&text=lexform&dpp=10&kwsz=5&p=2&mode=main&sr=1&spd=10&nodia=1&out=normal) — здесь есть интересные примеры.

Ты не болен, случайно? ― Как тебе сказать? Организм, **ха-ха,** держится только на молоке. Молоко ― это моя слабость. Ежедневно до десяти стаканов. [Василий Аксенов. Пора, мой друг, пора (1963)]

― Про обмундирование! ― Рот фронт, ребята! **Ха-ха!** Адъё! Товарищ младший лейтенант! [Александр Солженицын. В круге первом, т.1, гл. 1-25 (1968) // «Новый Мир», 1990]

Чтобы уж точно не ошибиться, что ресторан самый дорогой, **ха-ха…** [Виктор Пелевин. Бэтман Аполло (2013)]

А еще за ней ухаживал англичанин, который, как и вы **(ха-ха!)**, работал на английскую разведку и как-то назначил ей встречу... [Нина Щербак. Роман с филфаком // «Звезда», 2010]

**Дополнение**
При использовании вставки с междометием чаще всего внутри конструкции ставится восклицательный знак (для этого, собственно, и нужны тире или скобки).

> А о Марамзине я заговорил сам ― мол, дурно все-таки вы работаете, на правах доброжелателя **(хи-хи!)** доверительно вам это сообщаю...
> В. Соловьев. Три еврея, или Утешение в слезах

И разве мыслимо это сравнить? То военный вопрос, а то ― **хи-хи!** ― женский? Тоже мне ― сравнил! [Сергей Залыгин. Комиссия (1976)]